# TypeError: data[0] is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make an input file autocomplete when the user starts to type. I have tried, but when I start to type in input file it says `TypeError: data[0] is undefined`

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <input name="name" class="form-control" id="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Type here" 
   data-provide="typeahead" data-items="10" />
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('#typeahead').typeahead({


    source: function (query, process) {

        return $.getJSON(
            'api/usergroup/listdetails',
            { query: query },
            function (data) {
                var newData = [];
                $.each(data, function () {

                    newData.push(this.name);
                });

                process(newData); return;
            });
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Check your console .did you get any error there ? and also linked to the plugin which you are using

Comment: link is working fine, i have tested that and I can see data

Comment: Please provide the plugin official  link and you mean to say that you can see data in your console ?

Comment: yeah, I can see data in my console

Comment: Which one plugin are you using and can you provide the link or your dev environment ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure before calling your plugin you get the data.Check out the live example here.

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

As you provided information plugin getting called before data append .